# How to read multiple .txt files into a single buffer?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to read multiple text files into a single char* array in C. I can get as far as allocating the char* to the correct size (i.e. the sizes of all the text files summed up).

I tried to read each file, one by one, into their own buffer, then concatenate that buffer onto the end of the one that contains them all. This is all done in a for-loop. But when I print it out to make sure it worked, only the last file that was read is printed out.

I have also tried fread, but that seems to overwrite the buffer that it writes to, rather than append to the end of it.

Here is my code, most of it is from another SO thread:

```
for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
char *buffer = NULL;
size_t size = 0;

/* Get the buffer size */
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); /* Go to end of file */
size = ftell(file); /* How many bytes did we pass ? */
/* Set position of stream to the beginning */
rewind(file);
/* Allocate the buffer (no need to initialize it with calloc) */
buffer = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*buffer)); /* size + 1 byte for the \0 */
/* Read the file into the buffer */
fread(buffer, size, 1, file); /* Read 1 chunk of size bytes from fp into buffer */
/* NULL-terminate the buffer */
buffer[size] = '\0';

allFiles = strcat(allFiles, buffer);
free(buffer);
fclose(file);
}
```

Please help me out, I am stumped by what seems like a simple thing to do in C. Thanks.

Comment: There's no point in reading files into their own buffer. Just read them into the single buffer.

Comment: My guess would be you are overwriting the contents each time instead of appending, but it's difficult to know without some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing everything correct, but you need to increment the pointer before you pass it to `fread` for the next file otherwise you'll overwrite the beginning of the file over and over.

Assuming `buf` is the correct size for all the files +1 for the nul byte and files is an array of `char *`'s containing the filenames `NUM_FILES` long, you'll need to do something like this.

```c
char *p = buf;
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++) {
    FILE *f = fopen(files[i], "rb");

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long bytes = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fread(p, (size_t)bytes, 1, f);
    p += bytes;

    fclose(f);
}
*p = 0;
```

Comment: this mostly makes sense to me, but can you explain what p and buf represent in this? Is buf the single buffer that all files are being written to, or a buffer for a single file?

Comment: `buf` is the buffer you allocate after you calculate how large all the files are. `p` is initially a pointer to that buffer, but as you read files in using `fread`, you add the number of bytes you read to `p` so that the next file will be read in after the previous file.

Comment: this looks like it should work, but when I put it in my code and added a printf to print the `buf`, it still comes up empty.

Comment: I meant to say I printed `p`, and it still came up empty. Maybe I am allocating the space for the single buffer incorrectly?

Comment: `p` points to the end of `buf` after reading the files, to the very end of a very long string. Print `buf` to see the contents of all the files.

Comment: Also, see the edit I made to the code. You really should close files when you're finished with them.